# How to combine Multiple sentences in a dataframe column to a single list of elements in Python

Tags: python, nlp, text-analytics-api

I have a text column in my dataframe which looks like this

```
           col_name
Row 1      My name is John
Row 2      I live in London
Row 3      I work for an IT firm
Row 4      I travel once in a month
```

Now I want the text in all four rows to be combined as multiple elements in a list

```
output_list = ["My name is John","I live in London","I work for an IT firm","I travel once in a month"]
```

How to create the output list in the above format in Python

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
output_list = df.col_name.tolist()
```

Value:

```
['My name is John',
 'I live in London',
 'I work for an IT firm',
 'I travel once in a month']
```

Comment: Thanks. What if i want to create multiple list or to select only certain rows to be in a list.

Comment: e.g.["My name is John","I travel once in a month"] only 1st and 4th row to form a single list

Comment: Use this `df.col_name[[0,-1]].tolist()` to get the 1st and last rows